# Silex SessionProvider not setting inside my class

Tags: php, session, silex

I've started a Silex project a week ago and still getting some issues within the service-container. Although being quite simple.

Here is what happens to me:

```
$app->post('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

$success = (new \Malendar\Application\Service\User\LoginUserService($app['user_repository'], $app['session']))->execute($request);
if ($success) {
    return $app->redirect($app["url_generator"]->generate("calendar"));
} else {
    return new Response($app['twig']->render('login.html', ['formError' => true]), 400);
}});
```

I've created a LoginUserService class that given my user respository and the session service I'm able to login the user, that means, compare to database and checking that both username and password are in the system. That works perfectly but the issue comes with the session provider. Here is the class code:

```
class LoginUserService implements ApplicationServiceInterface
{
    private $userRepository;
    private $session;

    public function __construct(UserCaseRepository $userRepository, Session $session)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function execute($request = null)
    {
        // TODO: Implement execute() method.
        $userName = $request->get('user');
        $password = $request->get('password');
        $user = $this->userRepository->findByUsername($userName);
        var_dump($user);
        if (!empty($user) && $user->validate($password)) {
            $this->session->start();
            $this->session->set('id', $user->getUserId());
            $this->session->set('username', $user->getName());
            $this->session->set('email', $user->getEmail());
            $this->session->save();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

$this->session which I believe gets the app['session'] do not set the value of username, email and id, they remain null, and I can assure you that all data is well provided.

On the other hand, If I'm doing it outside the class, it works and the username it is set:

```
$app->post('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    $success = (new \Malendar\Application\Service\User\LoginUserService($app['user_repository'], $app['session']))->execute($request);
    $app['session']->set('username', 'Pedro');
```

But of course it would like to pursue the usage of my loginService what do I am missing?

Thank you beforehand =)

Comment: Silly question but worth to check, are you registering [SessionProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/session.html), aren't you? BTW, you would probably type hint against the [interface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionInterface.php#L21) and not the implementation. Also make sure your code goes through the path to set variables in session (put a ```var_dump``` or a ```die``` there, or even better use a debugger :-)

Comment: @mTorres Thanks for the reply. Session provider is registered like this:
`$app->register(new SessionServiceProvider());`
You are right i should get the Interface instead of UsercaseRepo, thanks =)
I've type and echo and its shown, so the code runs:
`if (!empty($user) && $user->validate($password)) {
            echo 'hi';
            $this->session->start();
            $this->session->set('id', $user->getUserId());
            $this->session->save();
            return true;
        }`

Comment: @mTorres I've just var_dump the $this->session after the setters and params are not setting. The var_dump is quite big but params like: `protected 'started' => boolean false ` and it does not show any of my persisted

Comment: I would go with the debugger to check what are doing the ```$this->session->set()``` calls, because from here I'm out of ideas, sorry :-(

Comment: Okay, I do not know why but now its working through the page controllers, although getting null though the unit-test. By doing the same but in this case having `$app['session.test'] = true; $app['session.storage'] = new MockArraySessionStorage();`
 
my app['session']->get(id) is null

Comment: You don't need to specify the *session.storage* service, [when using *session.test* it's set automatically by the provider](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Provider/SessionServiceProvider.php#L43). Keep in mind that you have to set *session.test* to true **after** registering the SessionProvider, as [the provider sets it to false](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Provider/SessionServiceProvider.php#L39)